# Cannot find my boot partition!

Tags: boot, reboot

I have a server, which I didn't install, that holds 2 versions of Ubuntu, 16 and 18. It boots automatically on the 16 version which I don't want as it causes problem with some softwares. I am unable to have to boot on the 18 version automatically.

To boot on the 18 version, I must choose it from the grub menu at boot time. The grub menu entry reads `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/sdj4)` **but there is no sdj4**!

lsblk shows this:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2714
loop1     7:1    0 116,8M  1 loop /snap/core/14946
loop3     7:3    0 116,8M  1 loop /snap/core/14784
loop4     7:4    0    73M  1 loop /snap/core22/583
loop5     7:5    0 452,4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/56
loop6     7:6    0  63,3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1852
loop7     7:7    0   2,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/884
loop8     7:8    0 460,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/65
loop9     7:9    0 162,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop10    7:10   0  63,3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1828
loop11    7:11   0  72,9M  1 loop /snap/core22/547
loop12    7:12   0   2,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/178
loop13    7:13   0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop14    7:14   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop15    7:15   0   476K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/781
loop16    7:16   0   1,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/181
loop17    7:17   0 164,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop18    7:18   0 346,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop19    7:19   0   2,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/920
loop20    7:20   0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop21    7:21   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop22    7:22   0   556K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/112
loop23    7:23   0   704K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/741
loop24    7:24   0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop25    7:25   0   696K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/115
loop26    7:26   0  81,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop27    7:27   0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2721
sda       8:0    0   7,3T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0   7,3T  0 part
└─sda9    8:9    0     8M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0   7,3T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0   7,3T  0 part
└─sdb9    8:25   0     8M  0 part
sdc       8:32   0   7,3T  0 disk
├─sdc1    8:33   0   7,3T  0 part
└─sdc9    8:41   0     8M  0 part
sdd       8:48   0   7,3T  0 disk
├─sdd1    8:49   0   7,3T  0 part
└─sdd9    8:57   0     8M  0 part
sde       8:64   0   7,3T  0 disk
├─sde1    8:65   0   7,3T  0 part
└─sde9    8:73   0     8M  0 part
sdf       8:80   0 447,1G  0 disk
├─sdf1    8:81   0   1,9G  0 part /boot
├─sdf2    8:82   0  30,5G  0 part
├─sdf3    8:83   0 293,7G  0 part /home
├─sdf4    8:84   0    63G  0 part /
└─sdf5    8:85   0  58,1G  0 part
sdg       8:96   0   7,3T  0 disk
├─sdg1    8:97   0   7,3T  0 part
└─sdg9    8:105  0     8M  0 part
sdh       8:112  0   7,3T  0 disk
├─sdh1    8:113  0   7,3T  0 part
└─sdh9    8:121  0     8M  0 part
nvme0n1 259:0    0   3,7T  0 disk
nvme1n1 259:1    0   3,7T  0 disk
```

How is that possible?

[image: grub menu entries]

Comment: This is why fstab and grub accept UUID definitions.  Boot into 16.04, find the UUID of the 18.04 root partition, and then modify the 18.04 grub entry to use UUID.  Just as importantly, edit the 18.04 `/etc/fstab` to use UUIDs.

Comment: @RonJohn so you mean that I can trust the output of lsblk listing sdf1 as being the partition from which the server is booted on?

Comment: Absolutely... **IF** /dev/sdf1 is the 18.04 boot disk (though I'd use `blkid` instead of `lsblk`).  The whole point of a partition's UUID is that it never changes, while the device number can.

Comment: The reference to sdj just have been because that was the drive when installed. Note that 18.04 reaches end of standard support in June, 2023. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases You should be planning 20.04 or 22.04 unless you have extended support.

Comment: @RonJohn solved, thank you very much! I did as you said but I didn't understand of to use the UUID in grub, instead, I've copied the menuentry string I wanted (Ubuntu 18.04.3....) to /etc/default/grub as GRUB_DEFAULT value and then update-grub. I now have a glimpse at the depth of my ignorance regarding the boot process